# Resampling pandas dataframe is deleting column

Tags: python, pandas

```
                    Val         ts  year  doy     interpolat  region_id
2000-02-18          NaN  950832000  2000   49           NaN      19987
2000-03-05          NaN  952214400  2000   65           NaN      19987
2000-03-21          NaN  953596800  2000   81           NaN      19987
2000-04-06  0.402539365  954979200  2000   97           NaN      19987
2000-04-22   0.54021746  956361600  2000  113           NaN      19987
```

The above dataframe has a datetime index. I resample it like so:

```
df = df.resample('D')
```

However, this resampling results in this dataframe:

```
                    ts  year  doy    interpolat  region_id
2000-01-01  1199180160  2008    1             1      19990
2000-01-02         NaN   NaN  NaN           NaN        NaN
2000-01-03         NaN   NaN  NaN           NaN        NaN
2000-01-04         NaN   NaN  NaN           NaN        NaN
2000-01-05         NaN   NaN  NaN           NaN        NaN
```

Why did the 'Val' column disappear? and all the other columns seem messed up too. See [Linearly interpolate missing rows in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34253838/linearly-interpolate-missing-rows-in-pandas-dataframe) for an explanation of where the dataframe is coming from.

--EDIT
Based on @unutbu's questions:

```
df.reset_index().to_dict('list')

{'index': [Timestamp('2000-02-18 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2000-03-05 00:00:00'), Timestamp('2000-03-21 00:00:00'), ... '0.670709965', '0.631584375', '0.562112815', '0.50740686', '0.4447712', '0.47880806', nan, nan]}
```

-- EDIT: The csv file for the above data frame in its entirety is here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/dp76hk6yfs6c1og/test.csv?dl=0

Comment: The resampled df has values for January and Year=2008 while the original df only starts in February and Year=2000?

Comment: that's right, not sure how the resampled df has year=2008. The original df starts in feb 2000

Comment: Have you tried simply print(df) before resample? Looks like these are different dataframes. Resample shouldn't have this type of effect.

Comment: I did, before resample it is fine.

Comment: Please post `df.reset_index().to_dict('list')` so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: thanks @unutbu, updated question to respond to your query

Comment: hmm, the 'index' seems to start fine, but at the end the values are defn not datetime's

Comment: Can you show `df.info()`? Are you sure the `Val` column has a numerical dtype?

Comment: So, the Val column has an object dtype. If I coerce it to float, then the problem goes away. @joris, if you can write your query as answer, I will accept

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `Val` columns will probably not have a numerical dtype for some reason, and all non-numerical (eg `object` dtype) columns are removed in `resample`.

To check, just look at `df.info()`.
To convert it to a numerical columns, you can use `astype(float)` or the `convert_objects` (`pd.to_numeric` starting from v0.17).