# How to apply resample to a pandas Dataframe with not numerical value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I learned that `resample` cannot be applied with not numerical value from
[Resampling pandas dataframe is deleting column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257069/resampling-pandas-dataframe-is-deleting-column)
and, I would like to apply `resample('30S')` to the input df as in the following:

Input_DF:

```
    eventTime          uuid  ts                   m_op  op.prg  op.tr     w.cycle cycle_type
0  2017-04-27 01:22:22 id1  2017-04-27 02:30:30   w     0.0     01:34:48  3       type_a                                                       
1  2017-04-27 01:23:16 id1  2017-04-27 02:31:00   w     1.0     01:33:54  3       type_a                                                      
2  2017-04-27 01:25:10 id1  2017-04-27 02:41:00   w     2.0     01:33:00  3       type_a                                                      
3  2017-04-27 01:25:32 id1  2017-04-27 02:42:45   w     3.0     01:32:00  3       type_a                                                     
4  2017-04-27 01:25:45 id1  2017-04-27 02:52:45   r     4.0     01:32:00  2       type_a
```

Output_DF

```
    eventTime          uuid  ts                   m_op  op.prg  op.tr     w.cycle cycle_type
0  2017-04-27 01:22:30 id1  2017-04-27 02:30:30   w     0.0     01:34:48  3       type_a                                                       
1  2017-04-27 01:23:00 id1  2017-04-27 02:30:30   w     0.0     01:34:48  3       type_a                                                       
2  2017-04-27 01:23:30 id1  2017-04-27 02:31:00   w     1.0     01:33:54  3       type_a                                                      
3  2017-04-27 01:24:00 id1  2017-04-27 02:31:00   w     1.0     01:33:54  3       type_a                                                      
4  2017-04-27 01:24:30 id1  2017-04-27 02:31:00   w     1.0     01:33:54  3       type_a                                                      
5  2017-04-27 01:25:00 id1  2017-04-27 02:31:00   w     1.0     01:33:54  3       type_a                                                      
6  2017-04-27 01:25:30 id1  2017-04-27 02:41:00   w     2.0     01:33:00  3       type_a                                                      
7  2017-04-27 01:26:00 id1             avg    +popular  3.5     Avg      +popular       type_a
```

where  `avg_of_the_values` compute the avg among the corresponding times, `+popular` fill with the most popular value or the first one -in case of two values with the same rank - and `Avg` is the usual mean.

I have been applying `groupBy` approach but it did not work.
Any suggestion would be very appreciated in advance. Many thanks in advance.carlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first solution that I implemented is based on splitting the entire problem in a number in subproblems - one for each column that is not numeric - and then merge the obtained solution. Below, I report part of the code that I used to solve  the case of `m_op`:

```
smart_sub_schema_Operation_progress=["eventTime","uuid", "m_op"]    
operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df=smart_home_df[smart_sub_schema_Operation_progress]
operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df['m_op'] = operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df['m_op'].map({'P':0, 'W': 1, 'R': 2, 'S': 3,  'F': 4})
operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df.eventTime = pd.to_datetime(operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df.eventTime)
operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df.index = operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df['eventTime']
resampled_operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df=operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df.resample('30S').reset_index()
resampled_operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df["m_op"]=resampled_operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df["m_op"].astype(float)
resampled_operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
resampled_operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df['m_op'] = resampled_operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df['m_op'].map({0.0:'P', 1.0:'W', 2.0:'R', 3.0:'S',  4.0:'F'})
print(resampled_operation_progress_sub_smart_home_df.to_string())
```