# How to prevent resample -> aggregate from dropping columns?

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-resample

Code

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data = {'A': [1, 1, 2], 'B': [None, None, None]},
    index = pd.DatetimeIndex([
        '1990-01-01 00:00:00',
        '1990-01-01 12:00:00',
        '1990-01-02 12:00:00'
    ])
)
print(df.resample('1d').aggregate('mean'))
```

Output

```
              A
1990-01-01  1.0
1990-01-02  2.0
```

Desired output

```
              A     B
1990-01-01  1.0  None 
1990-01-02  2.0  None
```

I don't care whether there's `None`, `np.nan` or `pd.NA` in column B of the output, the problem is that B is dropped.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Resampling pandas dataframe is deleting column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34257069/resampling-pandas-dataframe-is-deleting-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resample` will drop the non numeric columns when using a numeric aggregation. You can [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) after aggregation:

```
df.resample('1d').aggregate('mean').reindex(df.columns, axis=1)
```

output:

```
              A   B
1990-01-01  1.0 NaN
1990-01-02  2.0 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df.resample('d').agg({'A':'mean','B':'mean'})

          A   B
1990-01-01  1.0 NaN
1990-01-02  2.0 NaN
```

Comment: Answers are usually more helpful if they have some commentary for how/why they solve a problem.